# mysql 5.1.44: -e not executing and exiting properly on OSX

Tags: osx-lion, mysql, xampp

This function works on 5.0.75 on Ubuntu, but not on 5.1.44 on OSX (Lion):

```
mysql --database=sps --host=localhost --user=root --password=somepass -e "SELECT 1;"
```

The expected output is this:

```
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 | 
+---+
```

On OSX, though, it just dumps me to a mysql prompt awaiting a command, without ever executing the command specified by the -e switch.

Any idea why it doesn't execute and exit back to the command line as it should?